# Sony Cybershot LCD screen replacement, inverted colors

Tags: repair, sony, lcd

I bought a new LCD screen to replace the damaged one on my Sony Cybershot WX70 camera. After installing the screen and switching the camera back on, the colors on the display appear inverted. Black/shade is luminous red, blue is pink, pink is blue, although green and white are as they should be. Everything looks kind of pyschedelic.

I thought it must be a problem with the screen, so I contacted the seller (I bought the screen on Ebay) who kindly sent me another one for free. However, after receiving and installing it, the exact same thing happens. So it seems the problem is with the camera itself, possibly with how I have reassembled it.

Basically I just wanted to ask if anyone could tell me what would make the colors appear in this way? If I knew this then I'd have some idea of how to fix it. Just to add that the camera itself works fine as I've taken a few photos and viewed them on my PC.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: This *may* get closed as off-topic as it is about a piece of technology not unique to photography (i.e. an LCD screen).

Answer (score 2):

Usually connectors are "keyed" so they'll only go in one way, but it sounds like you got the wiring installed incorrectly. Check all the connectors between the camera and screen to be sure that they are inserted the right way and that you haven't forced any in backwards.

Comment: Usually, inserting a flat flex to an LCD module in reverse would either not work at all or destroy the LCD and/or upstream circuit board, not give you inverse colors :)